# Read the data from specific line in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a sequence of data files(".tab" files) with more than 11100 rows and 236 columns. Data begins from 297th line in one file and from 299th line in another file. How can I read the data from 297th row of each file in MATLAB R2014a?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, bu it seems that a typical machine's memory can handle such a file size. In that case, you can use `textscan` or `textread` MATLAB built-in functions.
Nonetheless, if you really cannot import your data into MATLAB environment, set `HeaderLines` argument of `textscan` to the line of interest. A simple example can be found in MATLAB documentations, or:

```
SelectedData = textscan(ID,formatSpec,'HeaderLines',296); % Ignore 296 first lines of the data
```

Comment: I have to read more than three or all the files from that folder and each file should start to read from 297th line. What should I do to read the data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I strongly recommend to review the MATLAB documentation. Assuming you have several files in hand (stored in `fileNames`:

```
for i = 1:numel(fileNames)
    ID = fopen(fileNames{i});
    formatSpec = '%s %[^\n]'; % Modify this based on your file structure
    SelectedData{i} = textscan(ID,formatSpec,'HeaderLines',296);
    fclose(ID);
end
```

`SelectedData` is a cell string containing all your data extracted from corresponding data (`fileNames`)